# Removing whitespace from each value in a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, strip

I want to write a function where I remove whitespace from the front and back of each string in a list.

This is my list called `t`:

```
['Specialty Food',
 ' Restaurants',
 ' Dim Sum',
 ' Imported Food',
 ' Food',
 ' Chinese',
 ' Ethnic Food',
 ' Seafood']
```

When I use `t[4].strip()`, I get the result of **'Imported Food'**. Okay, whitespace in the front removed successfully - great.

Now, when I try to do the same for each value in the list in a for loop, I get an error. I don't understand why.

This is my for loop:

```
for i in t:
    t[i] = i.strip()
```

This is my error:

```
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [204], in <cell line: 1>()
      1 for i in t:
----> 2     t[i] = i.strip()
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: What you tried to achieve?  We can guess, but rather not.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`enumerate` loop paradigm](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-enumerate-python-enum-for-loop-index-example/)

Comment: As @DanielHao Said, What is Your Motive? What Do You want The Code to Do Exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for i in t:` says *"Loop through my list called `t` and assign each value to variable `i`"*. `i` through each iteration will take string values stored in the list. So `t[i]` doesn't make any sense.

For instance the fist iteration would be

```
 t['Specialty Food'] = 'Specialty Food'
```

List indexes must be integers or slices, and the string `'Specialty Food'` in `t['Specialty Food']` is not an integer nor a slice.

Instead consider list comprehension:

```
t = [i.strip() for i in t]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate()` to get the index of each entry.

```
for idx,i in enumerate(t):
    t[idx] = i.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you JNevill, your comment pointed out a flaw in my coding logic.

I fixed the for loop:

```
for i in range(len(t)):
    t[i] = t[i].strip()
```

My code is no longer producing an error and I'm getting the desired result, which is the following list with no whitespaces in the front or back of each string:

```
['Specialty Food',
 'Restaurants',
 'Dim Sum',
 'Imported Food',
 'Food',
 'Chinese',
 'Ethnic Food',
 'Seafood']
```

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay away from indices and in-place mutations, I would suggest you use some functional aspects of Python to do the same operation.

```
t = ['Specialty Food', ' Restaurants', ' Dim Sum', ' Imported Food', ' Food', ' Chinese', ' Ethnic Food', ' Seafood']
new_t = map(lambda x: x.strip(), t)
print(new_t)
```